# auto height for a html div auto scrolling - Div to take remaining height

Tags: html, css

i have a very simple but confusing problem what issue i am having is that i have some div. first div which is fixed to top right with height 100% and this div has 2 more div inside div2 and div3 both should be scrolled .

one the uper div2 varies height from 100px to 200px after that it should be scrolling and the div with id div3 should take the remaining height and should be scrolling if data is increased.

i can achieve till div2 but the div3 is not taking the remaining height

my code is

```
    <div style="width:200px;height:100%;position:fixed;top:0px;right:0px;background:red;overflow:auto;">
<div style="width:100%;min-height:100px;max-height:200px;background:blue;overflow:auto;float:left;">
    ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>
</div>
<div style="width:100%;height:300px;background:yellow;float:left;overflow:auto;">
    ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/>ggdhhd<br/><br/>
</div>
```

i need something which is browser friendly..
if you can suggest me something it would be very helpful..

this is demo http://www.reurl.in/f84acc961

https://jsfiddle.net/fy727tLL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated fiddle:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fy727tLL/3/)

```html
<div style="width:200px;height:100%;position:fixed;top:0px;right:0px;background:red;overflow:auto;">
  <div style="width:100%;height:20%;background:blue;overflow:auto;float:left;">
    ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div style="width:100%;height:80%;background:yellow;float:left;overflow:auto;">
    ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>ggdhhd
    <br/>
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: here the fixed div is also scrollable div1 should not be be scrolable

Comment: For that you'll have to play in percentage for both the div2 and div3 as in https://jsfiddle.net/fy727tLL/3/

Answer (score 2):

The other option you can do is set div2 to a "fixed" height, and then set a margin above on div2 to the same height, then use an auto height. Here is a JSfiddle that does something very close to what you are doing, but it is a little more stylized and has fixed top divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/e13wzxgb/1/

```
#div2 {
position: absolute; 
top: 0;   
width: 800px; 
height: 100px; /*Height of top frame div*/
overflow: hidden; /*Disable scrollbars. Set to "scroll" to enable*/
background-color: navy;
color: white; 
}

#div3 {
position: fixed; 
top: 100px; /*Set top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv*/
height:auto;
margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
bottom: 0px; /*Set bottom value to HeightOfBottomFrameDiv*/
overflow: auto; 
background: #fff;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Hope that helps ya out!